# Show Another Model Data in Admin Grid Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working on a extension in which Customer subscribe for Promotion, when Customer subscribe I will save user id, product id.

In subscriber module, I have to show Customer Name and Product Name.

So My Question is how can we Show Another Model Data in Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your extension uses a grid that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`, you can modify the `_prepareCollection()` function to include data from other source (via joins). Also you will have to add new columns to the grid, which can be done in function `__prepareColumns()`.

For an example look at the grid block of the `Mage_Newsletter` module [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php)

Comment: Thanks.. it works !! When I trying to access `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); $name  = $product->getAttribute('name'); $name->getBackend()->getTable()`  Its gives me non object error .. do you have any idea how can I get attribute table name of Product

Comment: To get the model object for the attribute Name use this code instead: `$name = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')                ->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'name');` Then you could access the attribute property backend table via `$name->getBackendTable()`